# PyroCMS - custom module design, clear CSS formating from default design

Tags: jquery, css, pyrocms

I'm creating some custom modules on PyroCMS, and the problem is, that the default design that is inherited from global.css and other default design css files really messes with my new design and makes it harder to create a design for my custom modules.

writing !important on every line doesn't seem like a good option.

Also, I'm trying to add chromatable jQuery plugin, but it is not quite woring right, because the default CSS files ar conflicting with the design that plugin is trying to add.

Are there any good practices for doing this? Maybe there is a way I can clear or reset all CSS for my custom module design?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would prefer using different layout for the custom module.  PyroCMS allows you the create a completely different layout for each custom module you create, simply create a new layout with the name of your custom module in theme folder and it will be loaded automatically. With this feature you can include another CSS instead of you global.css . Refer this link
http://www.pyrocms.com/docs/1.3/manuals/designers/theme-layouts

Comment: I already started creating new theme, bet this could be more practical, tahnks. Also, is there a way I can use my custom layout for more than one module? Because I would like to use custom layout for all my custom modules.

Comment: Sure you can use separate custom layout for each custom module you create. You need to create a custom layout with the name of the custom module and PyroCMS will load the custom layout when the module is loaded.