# set_theme does not work in module pyroCMS 2.1

Tags: module, pyrocms

I create a custom theme with name "uni" in addons/default/themes. Ok this work because i can see it in CP.

Next i create a custom module with code :

```
class Server extends Public_Controller
{
public function __construct()
{
parent::__construct();

}
public function index()
{
$this->template->title($this->module_details['name'])->set_theme('uni')->build('test');

}
}
```

But when i browser this module, theme still is active theme on CP, so set_theme in module controller does not work.

Any way to make module using custom theme instead of change the active theme in CP?

Comment: Have you tried clearing your caches?

Comment: i dont set cache yet so no need to clear and in my pyro/assets/cache nothing there. in pyro\system\cms\cache have default folder but i delete it but nothing change

Answer (score 0):

I think that to change the "theme" on the front-end you need to use a custom page layout, not the set_theme

Comment: In pyrocms you can set only one theme for the front-end but you can also set a different layout via CP. http://www.pyrocms.com/docs/2.0/theming-pyrocms/theme-layouts

Comment: yes i got your idea. But this abit messy if you have two theme and put to one with 2 layout files. I mention here is two diffrerent theme not only different in page layout.

Answer (score 0):

If i have understood your question then this question is similar to [PyroCMS - custom module design, clear CSS formating from default design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546499/pyrocms-custom-module-design-clear-css-formating-from-default-design/9560570#9560570) and you can find solution there.

**Edited** 
Going through your explanation, i think you want to use two different layouts for the same module. I actually don't know how to do it in controller but i can hard code it. Actually the layout is loaded in `/system/appname/libraries/Template.php` so you can solve it by hard coding here. Here is the solution i have made in pyroCMS 1.3.2, it might be similar to version 2.1 or you can get some hints in solving your problem.

File to change `/system/appname/libraries/Template.php`. Find **build** function and find the condition and replace it.

```
if ($this->_layout)
{
    // Added to $this->_data['template'] by refference
    $template['body'] = $this->_body;
            $CI = &get_instance();

            if($CI->uri->segment(2) == 'backend'){
                    $this->_body =  self::_load_view('layouts/backend.html', $this->_data, TRUE, self::_find_view_folder());
            }
            else{
                    $this->_body =  self::_load_view('layouts/frontend.html', $this->_data, TRUE, self::_find_view_folder());
            }
    }
```

Comment: thank uttam, but let me explain again my question, i want to create one module call backend (with backend theme) and frontend module (with frontend theme). if set_theme work in custom  module, everything will be okie because i just need create two custom theme, and at backend module i call set_theme('backend') and in frontend module i call set_theme('frontend')

Comment: what i mean here is i have 2 custom modules and each module using one themes. Ty for this code but this is just for change layout file at CP and this is easy to do at 2.1 because set_layout work ok. What i concern is : theme has layout files, partial files and also css,js, image related. so if must using two layouts file at one theme, mean that you must mix two set of "img,js,css" to one theme directory and this a bit messy, rite?