# PyroCMS Custom Module Layout

Tags: pyrocms

I created a custom module called Drawings. I wanted to give it its own theme layout on the frontend, so I followed the advice I found [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546499/pyrocms-custom-module-design-clear-css-formating-from-default-design/9560570#9560570) - I put a layout file titled Drawings.html in my theme.

This had the correct effect on the frontend, but caused other problems and questions that I've been struggling to sort out:

1. The backend admin section for my module now uses the Drawings.html layout, which breaks its functionality completely. How can I set a specific layout for my module front end, but keep the standard admin backend layout (same backend implementation as in the [sample module](https://github.com/pyrocms/sample) tutorial)?
2. I read the following in the [Template Library](http://docs.pyrocms.com/2.1/manual/developers/tools/template-library): "When using Public_Controller and Admin_Controller, the layout is already set." Perhaps the solution involves using the set_layout function in these controllers somehow? All my attempts failed so far though.
3. I feel I am doing something incorrectly because now my module is not modular. For example, after creating the Drawings.html layout file in the theme, a statement like `{{ theme:css file="drawings.css"}}` in that layout file searches for those resources in my theme. So I have to put those JS and CSS resources in my theme, instead of in my module's CSS and JS folders. How do I keep and access my resources in the module's JS and CSS folders?

I don't know how this is supposed to work.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using front end controller use a layout there using philsturgeon template library like this

```
function index(){
    $this->template->set_layout('drawing')
                   ->build('yourview');
}
```

This way you can load a custom layout for your application.